# Support Vector Machine used in Image Classification

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, research, support-vector-machine, history

I am looking for a reference preferably a paper that details how Support Vector Machines (SVMs), and OpenCV were used to perform image classification before Convultional Neural Networks (CNNs). I am aiming to construct a SVM architecture that performs image classification. I would like to learn the history before CNNs came into play in AI history.